# clear richtextbox and overwrite previous entry

Tags: c#

I have a richtextbox that will overwrite a file that has already been saved before.

If I need to start a new file and then save it as a new file, it just overwrites the first file that was saved.

How can this be done?

```
String fileLocation;
    private void SaveMyFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var performSave = true;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLocation))
        {
            performSave = SetFileLocation();
        }
        if (performSave)
            richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileLocation, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

    }

    private bool SetFileLocation()
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
        saveFile1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|RTF Files|*.rtf";
        if (saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
        saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            fileLocation = saveFile1.FileName;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What action is the user doing to determine what is a new file?

Answer (score 0):

The fileLocation variable after the first save (SetLocation) is neither null or empty, that's why when you save again (click SaveMyFile button) it doesn't enters to the SetFileLocation Method and just performs the SaveFile

Comment: so can i set a verible that will save it as a new file if the richtextbox is empty. sorry im a complete newbie at this

Comment: as @Bernard said, in your "New File button" click event set the variable fileLocation to null

Answer (score 0):

When you "start a new file", just set `fileLocation` to null and you should get the `SaveFileDialog` to show up again to allow you to enter a new file location. The code below is the crucial bit:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLocation))
{
   performSave = SetFileLocation();
}
```

The `SetFileLocation()` method won't be called unless `fileLocation` is null or the empty string.

Comment: so what do i need to add to my code so it will allow me to "save as" if the richtextbox is empty

Comment: As I mentioned, set `fileLocation` equal to `null` wherever your code signals to "start a new file".